# Dubious matrix monotonicity

Tags: reference-request, matrices, matrix-analysis, order-theory, game-theory

Coming from a problem in game theory, I arose at some dubious monotonicity like property for matrices of the following art. Let $H=\lbrace h\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\colon h_{1}+\dots+h_{n}=0\rbrace$. I'm interested in matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which satisfy for all $h\in H$ and $i\ne j$
\begin{equation}
(h_{i}-h_{j})((Ah)_{i}-(Ah)_{j})\le0.
\end{equation} 
Does this property have a common name and has it been studied anywhere? What are sufficient conditions on $A$ for this property to hold? What else can be said about such matrices? For instance, one can easily check, that they must be conditionally negative semi-definite. I'm thankful for any remark, literature advice, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a matrix has the form $\theta I_n+ew^T+ve^T$ where $T$ denotes transposition and $e$ is the vector $(1,\ldots,1)^T$. The parameter $\theta$ is $\le0$.

Here is the proof when $n\ge4$. By continuity, your assumption implies that
$$(e\cdot h\quad\hbox{and}\quad h_i=h_j)\Longrightarrow((Ah)_i=(Ah)_j).$$
Denoting $B=A^T$, this means that $h\in(e,e_i-e_j)^\bot$ implies $h\in(B(e_i-e_j))^\bot$. Therefore there exists scalars such that
$$B(e_i-e_j)=\lambda_{ij}e+\theta_{ij}(e_i-e_j).$$
Writing $B(e_i-e_k)=B(e_i-e_j)+B(e_j-e_k)$ and using the fact that $e,e_i-e_j,e_i-e_k$ and $e_j-e_k$ are linearly independent when $i,j,k$ are pairwise distinct, you find that $\theta_{ij}=\theta$ does not depend upon the indices, and $\lambda_{ij}=w_i-w_j$ for some vector $w$. Finally, we obtain that the vector $v:=Be_i-\theta e_i-w_ie$ does not depend on the index $i$. Thus $B=\theta I_n+ew^T+ve^T$.

Comment: That's awesome (and a little bit disappointing at the same time)! Thank you anyway.